# ionic angular formbuilder not getting formcontrol value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have spent hours figuring why, I cant get any form value. There is no error in console. At this point i dont know what to check next! Everytime i hit on sign up even with the forms having a value in it. I have a null result when used "this.myForm.value".

//app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

//login.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Log in</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button
  expand="block"
  (click)="onSignUp()"
  >Submit</ion-button> 
</form>
```

//login.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [null, Validators.required],
      password: [null, Validators.required]
    }); 
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
    
  }

  onSignUp(): void {
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Log in</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignUp()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button
  expand="block"
   type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid"
  >Submit</ion-button> 
</form>
```

By using the **ngSubmit**, you link the button (**type="submit"**) to the form.
I added the **[disabled]="!myForm.valid"** to disable the button if inputs aren't valid.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that i didnt, include my component,in my module. I have nerver checked in my module because i thought it would be added automaticall